# Access db foreign key issue

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

Hi I have desktop app which is using MS access Database. All was fine till  added a foreign key in my table. I have 2 tables, first

`sections`

```
section_id | name
1          | Section1
2          | Section2
```

`Details`

```
details_id | Name | section_id
1          |Name1 |1
2          |Name2 |2
3          |Name3 |1
```

`section_id` from section table is foreign key to Details table.

I have a grid in which I am displaying all the data from details table and allow user to edit records. For section_id I am using a combobox, which allows user to select only from data present is Section table.

The gridview allows me to add a row but update throws an error

> You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'sections'.

Y would that be? I am only allowing user to enter predefined values from `section` table for `section_id` column in `details` table.

**Edit**
I noticed one thing.. I had used parametrised query to do update. and it was giving error. I changed it to normal query with `'"`, the query started to work properly. Any idea why?

**Edit2**

this is how my update code is:

```
//query = "UPDATE Details SET Name='" + lblName + "', section_id="+section_id;
//query += " WHERE details_id ="+details_id ;

query = "UPDATE Details SET Name =@Name, section_id=@section_id WHERE details_id = @details_id ";

cmd2.CommandText = query;
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", lblName );
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details_id ", details_id );
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section_id", section_id);
//cmd2.Parameters.Add("@section_id", OleDbType.Integer, 12).Value = Convert.ToInt32(section_id);                              
cmd2.Connection = con;
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I tried suggestion of @GordThompson, by adding datatype to the parameter. But still same issue.

**Another update**
I ran the code without using parametrised query. I noticed a strange behavior. I added a section_id in Details table say section_id=2, then deleted section_id=2 from Sections table. And the data from Details table for which I had added section_id is also gone. Is this the typical behavior of Ms Access?

Comment: are you trying to update `section_id` column ?

Comment: check this link - `http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/HV080760946.aspx`

Comment: This question is currently tagged 'sql-server'. Is there really a Microsoft SQL Server database involved here (in addition to the Access database)? If so, please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: Yes I am updating section_id

Comment: @GordThompson my bad! By mistake. I am actually used to adding that tag as I usually work in sql-server. This is first time I am working in MS-Access

Comment: @RohitGupta I checked that link. It apparently says that "error occurs if you try to change or insert a record in the "many" table in a one-to-many relationship, and that record does not have a related record in the table on the "one" side.". This is not the case in my scenario.

Comment: re: changing your query - You were probably passing parameters that were not strictly the correct type. The data access layer (e.g., OleDb or Odbc) relies on the type to know how to handle the column: `string` parameters for a `Text` column, `int` parameters for a `Long Integer` column, etc..

Comment: the `section_id` you are trying to update exists in the `section` table right ?

Comment: @RohitGupta No. the section_id column i am trying to update is in details table.

Comment: What is the data type of section_id in both tables?

Comment: Data type in both tables is OleDbType.Integer

Comment: Integer or Long Integer? Check it in Ms Access Tables design view.

Comment: It isn't because of the datatype as insert query runs without any issues. And also the update query without using parameter is working fine

Comment: @AlexBell I checked the datatype. Its long integer for both the columns

Comment: @Arti I meant the `value` which you are trying to update exists in section table right?

Comment: @RohitGupta :-( sorry. yes the value exists in section table.

Comment: by looking at above `section` table, you trying to update either `1` or `2` in details table's `section_id` column right ?

Comment: Yes, thats right @RohitGupta

Comment: Have you tried it with hard codded values ? Instead of passing values from variables try to hard code the values and see if you get the same error. I have tried it with hard codded values and it worked. 

also, what is the version of MS Access ? I tested this with MS Access 2010.

Comment: It works with hard coded values.